# pie chart rotating according to percentages fiddle css, jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating this pie chart, to display the percentage of `Yes` votes, against `No` votes..two sections only, two colors.

**PROBLEM**

I make it rotate.... the percentages of votes are correct, but the pie chart doesnt rotate according this percentages....

What am I doing wrong? The css setting of the pie maybe?

I attach the code snippet & here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fu8b3jq2/

```js
var red=0;
var blue=0;
var Psum = (red+blue);
var rotation = 0;

$(".VoteMain").on("click",function(){ 
if($(this).hasClass("VoteRed")){
 red++;
 Psum = (red+blue);
}
 if($(this).hasClass("VoteBlue")){ 
 blue++; 
  Psum = (red+blue);
}



var red_percentage= Math.floor((red/Psum)*100); 
var blue_percentage= 100-red_percentage;

//display percentages
    $(".VoteRed span").text(red_percentage+"% :" +red+" votes");
    $(".VoteBlue span").text(blue_percentage+"% :"+blue+" votes");

 //rotate pieChart
 
  $(".blue").rotate(blue_percentage);
 
 
});






//function
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    return $(this);
};
```

```css
.pie_container{
 
 margin:40px;
 
 
 
}
.pie{
 
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 0);
 qbackground:blue;
 border-radius:50%;
 
 
 
}
.blue{
 
 height:100px;
 width:50px;
 background:blue;
 float:right;
 
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.red{
 
 height:100px;
 width:50px;
 background:red;
 float:right;
 
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.VoteMain{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie_container">

<div class="pie">
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>

</div>

<div class="PollVoteMain">
<div class="VoteMain VoteBlue">blue <span>0</span></div>
<div class="VoteMain VoteRed">red <span>0</span></div>

</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/

hope this can help you [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pf11m662/):

```js
var red=0;
var blue=0;
var Psum = (red+blue);
var blue_percentage=0;
var red_percentage=0;

function doIt(blue, red, Psum){

 var red_percentage = Math.floor((red/Psum)*100); 
 var blue_percentage = 100-red_percentage;

 $('.percentages').text(
  'blue: '+blue_percentage+'% - red: '+red_percentage+'%'
 );



 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  //animationEnabled: true,
  //title: {
  // text: "Desktop Search Engine Market Share - 2016"
  //},
  data: [{
   type: "pie",
   startAngle: 240,
   yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
   indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
   dataPoints: [
    {y: blue_percentage, label: "blue"},
    {y: red_percentage, label: "red"},
    //{y: 7.06, label: "purple"},
    //{y: 4.91, label: "orange"},
    //{y: 1.26, label: "green"}
   ]
  }]
 });
 chart.render();

}

$('.btn-blue, .btn-red').on('click', function(){

 if($(this).hasClass('btn-blue')){
  blue++; 
  Psum = (red+blue);
 }
 if($(this).hasClass('btn-red')){
  red++;
  Psum = (red+blue);
 }
 
 doIt(blue, red, Psum);
 
 $(".VoteRed span").text(red_percentage+"% :" +red+" votes");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-blue">blue</button>
<button class="btn-red">red</button>
<span class="percentages">blue: 0%, red: 0%</span>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 160px; width: 100%;">
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: works great. thank you. the thing is I was expectig to doit without plugins